# Double value is boxed and then immediately unboxed in Java

Tags: java, integer, double, sonarqube

How can I avoid using all that casts in my code in order not to have my value boxed/unboxed by sonar ?

Here's my code :

```
Double value = (Double) input.get(0);

int integer = new Double(value).intValue();

Double dec = Math.abs(value - (new Double(integer ).doubleValue()));
```

I would like to avoid casting as much as I do, but I am not sure I can keep it boxed this way.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you create a new Double on the second line?

Comment: why are you using `Double` instead of `double` at all?

Comment: Because I need to use `.equals()`  on `dec` right after it.

Comment: You're making things too hard. Try `Double dec = value - Math.floor(value);`

Comment: Why do you create a new `Double` in the line `int integer = new Double(value).intValue();` if `value` is already a `Double`???

Comment: @hacks4life, if the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32884995/5387814) solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @AndyDavies, hey Andy, nope it didn't. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Could you explain why? If the answer didn't solve your question then your question probably needs rewording.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what type `input.get()` returns so I'll assume that the first cast is necessary. You don't need to instantiate new `Double` objects on every line, you can just call its methods to return the correctly-typed values you need.

```
Double value       = (Double) input.get();
int    integerPart = value.intValue();
double decimalPart = Math.abs(value - integer.doubleValue());
```

It looks like you're just trying to extract the integer and decimal parts of a double, in which case this code expresses the intent a bit more clearly:

```
Double value       = (Double) input.get();
int    integerPart = value.intValue();
double decimalPart = Math.abs(value - Math.floor(value));
```